# Cannot get IP on cloned VM LINUX7,8

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, udev

I have cloned a virtual machine running RHEL 7 and 8. I am not getting an ip address. After cloning the virtual machine, networking no longer functions. The `ifconfig` command does not show the network interface (for example, `eth0`), but may show a new one (for example, `eth1`). Restarting the server also same issue.

```
SIOCSIFADDR: no such device
eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
Bind socket to interface: no such device
Failed to bring up ethX
```

Reviewing the dmesg log with the command `dmesg | grep eth` may show a message similar to:

```
udev: renamed network interfaces ethX to ethY
```

I know on linux 6 we can delete/remove the contents of /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and reboot the server and we get the ip

How do we get ip on Linux 8? I don't find udev in linux 8

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

> The `ifconfig` command does not show the network interface (for example, `eth0`), but may show a new one (for example, `eth1`). Restarting the server also same issue.

When you cloned the server VM the new instance will have been assigned a new MAC address for the network interface. The server OS can no longer find the old MAC but can now find a new one. Since the server VM has assigned `eth0` to the interface with the original MAC it has to allocate `eth1` for the new one.

In the old world you would have removed the learned assignment under `/etc/udev/rules.d/`. Unfortunately although I can explain to you what the problem is, I can't give you specific direction on resolving the issue with RHEL 7 or 8.